# ImproperlyConfigured error with include to other url file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using [django-cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/) to bootstrap my project which will include api paths. Following the steps in [Two Scoops of Django 1.11](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11) to configure my urls to follow a similar pattern to this:

```
   api/foo_app/ # GET, POST
   api/foo_app/:uuid/ # GET, PUT, DELETE
   api/bar_app/ # GET, POST
   api/bar_app/:uuid/ # GET, PUT, DELETE
```

When I try to setup my project like this I'm getting the following error: 
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'my_project.core.api_urls' from /Users/username/Development/my_project/my_project/core/api_urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

My current setup:

#### my_project.config.settings.base.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'
DJANGO_APPS = [
    # Default Django apps:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Useful template tags:
    # 'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Admin
    'django.contrib.admin',
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',  # Form layouts
    'allauth',  # registration
    'allauth.account',  # registration
    'allauth.socialaccount',  # registration
    'rest_framework',
]

# Apps specific for this project go here.
LOCAL_APPS = [
    # custom users app
    'my_project.users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'my_project.core.apps.CoreConfig',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

#### my_project.config.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views import defaults as default_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/', include('my_project.users.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'^api/', include('my_project.core.api_urls', namespace='api')),
]
```

#### my_project.core.api_urls.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

urlpattenrs = [
    url(
        regex=r'^users/$',
        view=page_not_found,
    ),
]
```

The `core` app does not contain any models right now. It's just where I'm organizing all the URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"urlpattenrs" should be "urlpatterns" (in `my_project.core.api_urls.urls`) ;)

Comment: Is there a face palm emoji I can insert in there somehow??? Thank you. I was driving myself crazy. Will accept answer once the time permits me to